# Sufficient condition for positive semi-definiteness of the difference between outer products

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\alpha, \beta, \alpha^* \in R^+$ and $i = (1,1,1...1) \in R^k$. Also let $l = (1,1, ... ,0, ....1) \in R^k$

That is, $i$ is a k-dimensional vector of ones, and $l$ is a k-dimensional vector of an arbitrary number of zeros and ones.

Define

$A = (\beta-\alpha)ii' - \alpha^*ll'$

What are sufficient conditions on $\alpha, \beta$ and $\alpha^*$ for A to be positive semi-definite?

I have been stuck of this for a while now. My intuition tells me that $\beta > \alpha + \alpha^*$ is a sufficient condition, but I haven't been able to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $l$ is parallel to $i$, then $A$ is PSD iff $\beta-\alpha-\alpha^\ast\ge0$.

If $l$ is not parallel to $i$, then $A$ is PSD iff both $\beta-\alpha\ge0\ge\alpha^\ast$. Clearly $A$ is PSD when $\beta-\alpha\ge0\ge\alpha^\ast$. Conversely, suppose $A$ is PSD. As $i$ and $l$ are linearly independent, there are vectors $u$ and $v$ such that $\langle u,i\rangle=0\ne\langle u,l\rangle$ and $\langle v,i\rangle\ne0=\langle u,l\rangle$. So, in order that $u^\ast Au=-\alpha^\ast|\langle u,l\rangle|^2\ge0$ and $v^\ast Av=(\beta-\alpha)|\langle v,i\rangle|^2\ge0$, we must have $\beta-\alpha\ge0\ge\alpha^\ast$.

So, $\beta-\alpha\ge0\ge\alpha^\ast$ is a sufficient condition for $A$ to be PSD, regardless of whether $l$ is parallel to $i$ or not.